# Adduplex control raises InvalidOperationException on real phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, adduplex

I have Silverlight WP8 app, using AdDuplexWP8.2.8.0.9 sdk from Nuget. I've added my app on Adduplex.com, it is in Running state.

When I run it on simulator, it shows banners as expected. But when I try on real phone it raises:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException 
     Sequence contains no elements: at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

at  AdDuplex.WindowsPhone.DLL!AdDuplex.Models.ObstructionDetector.IsElementOnTop(Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame frame, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage page, System.Windows.FrameworkElement marker, out System.Windows.FrameworkElement culpritElement, bool isTest)
```

Is it because app version with adduplex isn't published yet?

As only one dll is included in both configs (ARM and x86), I suspect that something may be wrong with sdk itself, but this is the only sdk version I can work with.

Update: app is now in "Running" state.

P.S. Windows 8 version of app works pretty well, even pending.

Comment: I'd say wait after it's no longer pending and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Have you tried testing on several different phones? Which model phone is giving you the hard time?

Comment: Right now I have only one - nokia lumia 920

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about your app? Where are you placing the ad control? Is it a Pivot based app?

Comment: It is a WP8 monogame based app (based on XAML monogame template), AdControl is added to GamePage next to DrawingSurface. Works ok on any simulator, but fails on real nokia 920.

Answer (score 1):

The root of all evil was attempt to adjust position the adControl in runtime.

As end-user screen resolution is unknown in design time I can set DrawingSurface height, and without height explicitely specified it becomes zero. That's why I set adControl.Margin or DrawingSurface.Height in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game constructor. Everything worked on emulator (and in Win8 version), but on real device somehow messed with adDuplex code which examines adcontrol position and obscurity.

So far the solution is simple:

```
   <DrawingSurface x:Name="XnaSurface" Canvas.ZIndex="0" />
   <adduplex:AdControl x:Name="adDuplexAd"  AppId="{MyID}"
                            Canvas.ZIndex="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  />
```

But if you plan to move adControl, you should use transform raither than Margin or Width/Height.